# IFERROR within nested formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula gives `#DIV/0` if range is empty/blank. Instead, I would like result to be "" or "0" instead.

`=IFERROR("Total = $"&FIXED(SUBTOTAL(9,L3:L85),0,0)&"
≥ $10K Count = "&COUNTIF(L3:L85,">=10000"),"≥ $10K Count = 0")&"  or  "&FIXED(SUM(COUNTIF(L3:L502,">=10000")/COUNTA(L3:L502)*100),0)&"%"`

Can anyone suggest how to improve the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of your formula has the risk of an error of divide by zero:

`COUNTIF(L3:L502,">=10000")/COUNTA(L3:L502)*100`

So you just need to wrap that in another `IFERROR` function:

`IFERROR(COUNTIF(L3:L502,">=10000")/COUNTA(L3:L502)*100,0)`

And insert that back into the overall formula:

`=IFERROR("Total = $"&FIXED(SUBTOTAL(9,L3:L85),0,0)&"
≥ $10K Count = "&COUNTIF(L3:L85,">=10000"),"≥ $10K Count = 0")&"  or  "&FIXED(SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(L3:L502,">=10000")/COUNTA(L3:L502)*100,0)),0)&"%"`